# iOS UITextView hardly gets Focus

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uitextview

I have a TableView with some Cell's that contain a `UITextField` and some with a `UITextView`.

While presenting a `UITableViewController` i'm getting a strange behavior. The TextView has a property called "Selectable":

[image]

If I leave this checked, the last Cell that contains a `TextView` becomes automatically focused. And Of Course the keyboard will popup and hide content.

If I don't check it, it won't become focused when the view loads - that's what I want - but no touches in the Cell's TextView are not recognized.

So any idea why:

1. The Selectable property prevents any touches?
2. Whats the difference then between Selectable & Editable?

Any Solutions for my dilemma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `selectable` means that data detectors (dates, addresses, etc., in accordance with the `dataDetectorTypes` property setting) act as links.
- `editable` means that the user can type, select, copy, and paste the text itself.

Also, don't trust the Interface Builder (nib editor) interface on these properties. Set them in code.

Comment: Well.. your last advice helped. DONT TRUST IB. Still curious why Selectable automatically pushes focus to the TextView. I've set now all in code and everything is fine. Thx mate :)